# Smartgwt create a menu to store the buttons

Tags: button, menu, smartgwt

I am using smartgwt and I realize that there are too many buttons on the page.

So I want to create a menu button to store some of my buttons, if there are more than 3 buttons on my page, the other button will be hidden in a menu button, when the user click on "more buttons", the hidden buttons will be shown.

How can I add the buttons to menu?

[Menu button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgtvp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I find out the solution :

```
    for(int i = 4; lastIndex > i; lastIndex--) {    

        HStack editButtons = new HStack(1);
        editButtons.setDefaultLayoutAlign(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);  
        editButtons.setSnapTo("TR");  
        editButtons.setHeight("100%");
        editButtons.setWidth("100%");
        editButtons.setMembers(buttonLayout.getMember(lastIndex)); 

        MenuItem editMenuItem = new MenuItem("");  
        editMenuItem.setShowRollOver(false);  
        editMenuItem.setEmbeddedComponent(editButtons); 

        menu.addItem(editMenuItem);
        buttonLayout.removeMember(buttonLayout.getMember(lastIndex));

    }
```